# Proxy server vs /etc/hosts file

Tags: proxy, hosts, testing

I was told today that /etc/hosts is not a viable option for testing a new destination server. The DNS for /etc/hosts modifications could still cache the old DNS settings and we would get incorrect results on testing.

The only option we were given is to setup a proxy server and set the proxy info in each browser.

I am wondering if this is the case do I need to setup every browner on my machine to test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` does not use DNS at all so talking about DNS cache makes no sense.  This file is authoritative over DNS concerning name resolution, as specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (the Name Service Switch config file).

So if you enter a IP-host mapping in `/etc/hosts` it will always take precedence over DNS.  (Of course, unless you modified `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and you should have a good reason to do so.)

Comment: The only remark I have is: sometime is required to restart naming cache daemon

Comment: And to be precise, normally the hosts entry in nsswitch.conf is configured to `files dns`. If you exchange those two, DNS will take precedence over the /etc/hosts file.